# How to make sections of lists level

Tags: html, css

I'm having one of those days where I can't think of the correct wording to search on Google, and I've tried many things. I'm going to hit myself when I find out the answer...

You'll see that when you run my code below, the final "pm" on each line isn't level. How do I make each opening / finishing time level with each other?

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>Mon 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Tue 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Wed 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Thu 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Fri 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sat 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sun - Closed</li>
</ul>
```

I apologise for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple answers:

#### Text alignment

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none; text-align: right;">
    <li>Mon 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Tue 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Wed 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Thu 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Fri 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Sat 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Sun - Closed</li>              
</ul>
```

#### Font

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none; font-family: monospace;">
    <li>Mon 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Tue 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Wed 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Thu 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Fri 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Sat 7am - 7pm</li> 
    <li>Sun - Closed</li>              
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for fun, another way is the `attr()` black magic. You could use a `span` or whatever the result would be the same. You just need a fixed width `inline-block` element.

Browser support [from IE8](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent), so even in windows XP SP1 you'd have your hours aligned.

```css
li::before{
  content: attr(data-day);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  color: #888;
}

[data-day=Sun]{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li data-day="Mon">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Tue">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Wed">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Thu">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Fri">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Sat">7am - 7pm</li>
  <li data-day="Sun">Closed</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Whoa. That IS black magic. Of course, this method might hurt SEO and accessibility, but it's a neat trick that probably has a great use case I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Nice idea! +1 for thinking out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a monospace font:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Mon 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Tue 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Wed 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Thu 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Fri 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sat 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sun - Closed</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can align your items to the right:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  text-align: right;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Mon 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Tue 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Wed 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Thu 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Fri 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sat 7am - 7pm</li>
  <li>Sun - Closed</li>
</ul>
```

Try to avoid inline styles, as they are considered bad practice.